# Not to translate certain words on azure translation API v2

Tags: symfony, azure-api-apps, azure-cognitive-services

On My website I have a form using azure cognitive service translation API v2.
When the user fill the form the other tabs are automatically translated upon submitting.

I want the form not to translate certain words for eg : "North Dice".Because it's a brand

I found this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/dynamic-dictionary

saying that basically I have to add dictionnary words like this :

phrase

But the thing is I don't know where I have to put it. I tried uploading file of dictionnary word in the custom translation site. But it doesn't seem to work.
There is also translation hub but I don't get the difference between hub and custom site...

So If somone could tell me where should I add these dictionary syntax that would be great!
Also I use symfony

Thank you

[Form automatically translated on other tabs]

Comment: I found this https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1166938-hub-building-a-custom-system-using-a-dictionary-o

Comment: I'd like to know if I need to modify something

Answer (score 0):

> On My website I have a form using azure cognitive service translation API v2.

The Microsoft Translator team has released Version 3 (V3) of the Translator Text API. V2 is **deprecated** on April 30, 2018 and will be **discontinued** on **April 30, 2019**.

So I recommend that you  migrate Translator Text API V2 to V3. For information, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/migrate-to-v3).

> So If someone could tell me where should I add these dictionary syntax that would be great! Also I use symfony

I am not familiar with symfony, but from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate?tabs=curl#translate-with-dynamic-dictionary), we could know how to use the it with CURL. I think you could implement it easily.

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=de" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <client-secret>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{'Text':'The word <mstrans:dictionary translation=\"North Dice\">word or phrase</mstrans:dictionary> is a dictionary entry.'}]"
```

The result:

```
[
    {
        "translations":[
            {"text":"Das Wort "North Dice" ist ein Wörterbucheintrag.","to":"de"}
        ]
    }
]
```